# Android failure delivering result resultinfo when loading camera image

Tags: android, android-camera

Iam trying to load an image after capturing image from camera, But iam getting 
"failure delivering result resultinfo" error. Below are the values when i get the error:

resultCode = -1

requestCode = 0

data= null

why the Intent data is coming as null? What is the issue with this code?

```
int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo",  "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileSettings.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        if (items[item].equals("Take Photo"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg")));

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
        else if (items[item].equals("Cancel"))
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    });

    builder.show();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mainImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why the Intent data is coming as null?

You are providing `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. If you do so, there is no requirement for the camera app handling your request to return a result via an `Intent`. After all, you do not need the result, as you know where the full-size image was written: to the location you indicated via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @Abhi1988: Stop trying to use the `Intent`, and just use the location you provided in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.